# Как сделать невидимым последний элемент списка listview в Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

Имеется список listview. Как обратиться к последнему элементу списка и сделать его невидимым? Но при этом он должен всё ещё занимать место в списке. 
Или как сделать так, чтобы слушатель скрола списка делал бы последний элемент невидимым?

Comment: в адаптере последнюю строку не заполняйте

Comment: @Style-7 Можно подробнее? У меня адаптер состоит из отдельного класса.

Comment: чтобы получить какие то подробности, вам нужно как минимум добавить код адаптера. из того, что вы сочли нужным сообщить о своей проблеме сейчас, можно посоветовать последнему айтему (position = items.lenght) ставить свойство invisible, тогда view не будет отображаться, но будет занимать место.

Comment: если таким способом вы хотите сделать отступ от нижнего края, то это плохая идея, так как последнего элемента никто никогда не увидит, в то же время, раз он есть, то в нем есть какая то информация, которая появилась явно не для того, чтобы быть никому не видимой